# PHP: message box in the same page

Tags: php

I have a form called orderform. now i want to order the equipment. after i ordered the things, the details are stored in the database, and the mail will sent to the server. i got the above mentioned processes. but it goes to the another page. I want all these process should be done with in the same page. that means after i hit the submit button  the mail send to the server and the data store in the database and a message box will display with in the same page that contains the details with the order. could u pls help me? 
regards, 
vinoth

Answer (score 1):

the technology you should use is called AJAX. Just google it. There's plenty of information about it. There is jQuery library that deals pretty nice with this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to done it.

1.Put `action of a form  empty  so it will be redirect to same PHP page`  and on that page you can perform database handling and mail functionality. and then in form (HTML code) Put `value = "$_POST['fieldname']"`. Please see example below

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST)){
            //Perform database insert operation
            //Mail Operation
            //Set message.
    }
?>
<?php if(isset($message) && !empty($message)) { echo $message; }?>
 <form name="frmname" id="frmname" action="" method="post">
       <input type="name" id = "name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) { echo $_POST['name'];}" />
       <input type="submit" name="sbmt" id="sbmt" value="post" />
 </form>
```

2.Use Jquery `jQuery.post()` method. Please find below url for it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

thanks